# Scan Twitter Followers, API call issue

Tags: twitter

I want to get followers who are likely SPAM (With my algo like profile have no  more than 10 twits, default profile picture etc..)

But suppose a profile have 1k followers, Its too hard to get all the data from that profile with 150 api call request.

Is there any other idea to do that ? Any third party api to get profile data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with **two** API calls.

First, you want to [get all the followers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=evilspammer
```

That will return up to 5,000 user IDs.

Then, post those IDs to [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup)

You will then get back the full profile of all the users following your spammer.

Comment: Thanks, i got it https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=45369648, But what about the rest (if more than  5000 ) How to get theme ?

Comment: Can i use this one http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/ajaypatel_aj.json will it give me all followers data or not?

Comment: Read the documentation about how to use the cursor https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

Comment: Yes i got it. How much user information i can look up i n single call ?

Comment: You can get up to 5000 users with a single call.

Comment: How much i can scan ? at single call ?